# Sending encrypted data with UDP - Openssl c++

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, openssl

Below are the partial codes of my udp server and client.
I am not sure is it the issues with UDP that my output is wierd but it is always on the 16th word that something is wrong?

```
define MAX_ENCRYPT_MSG_SIZE 16
```

On the server side :

```
char tempStr[MAX_ENCRYPT_MSG_SIZE];

 /***** GET INPUT CODE HERE *****/

int tempLen = strlen(tempStr)+1;

//encrypt msg
ct = aes_encrypt(ci->getEVPCipherEN(),(unsigned char*) tempStr, &tempLen);

//send msg
rc = sendto(*(ci->getSd()), ct, tempLen, 0,(struct sockaddr *) ci->getCliAddr(),*(ci->getCliLen()));
```

On the Client Side :

```
int iLen = MAX_ENCRYPT_MSG_SIZE;
char msg[MAX_ENCRYPT_MSG_SIZE];

n = recvfrom(*(ci->getSd()), msg, iLen, 0,(struct sockaddr *) ci->getCliAddr(),ci->getCliLen());

char pt[16];
char *plaintext = (char *)aes_decrypt(ci->getEVPCipherDE(),(unsigned char*) msg, &iLen);
//convert back to only 16 bytes
strcpy(pt,plaintext);
if(plaintext == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
}       
else
{
    std::cout << pt << std::flush;
}
```

Output :

[image: Sample out put of client side]

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c strings need space for a null byte in the end? is that it?

Comment: Sorry can you kindly elaborate further? i don't quite understand which part is wrong.

Comment: are you sure that you have the space for the 0-byte in the array , which is required to terminate char-array based strings in c?

Comment: also you are feeding iLen to decrypt and not the actual received data size?

Comment: for encrypt you give tempLen+1?

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way, so you are saying msg[MAX_ENCRYPT_MSG_SIZE] should be msg[MAX_ENCRYPT_MSG_SIZE + 1]?

Comment: im spliting the msg to every 16 characters so my tempLen is always 16. is there a better way to do this? as there is no way for the client to know the original packet size right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14708/discussion-between-dupdupdup-and-markus-mikkolainen)

Comment: Doesn't the `send()` function truncate null terminators?

Comment: @Littlegator No, it certainly does not. It sends what you tell it to send, as described by the pointer and the length.